# Binding in WPF window only works occasionally when removing content from window

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, user-controls, ivalueconverter

I have a strange situation wherein I have a binding with a converter in a WPF window. Occasionally, the content of this window is removed from said window and inserted into a tabbed window like so:

```
        public void AddNewTab(Window wpfWindow, String tabTitle, OnFocusHandler onFocusHandler)
    {
        //Unhook window contents
        object content= wpfWindow.Content;
        wpfWindow.Content = null;

        //Create a new tab
        TabItem newTab = new TabItem();
        newTab.Header = title;

        newTab.Style = (Style)Resources["CorsairTab"];

        //newTab.Foreground = Brushes.White;
        newTab.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
        newTab.Content = content;

        //Add it
        TabControl.Items.Add(newTab);

        //Tie handler if it exists
        if (onFocusHandler != null)
            _listOnTabSelectedEventHandlers.Add(onFocusHandler);
        else
            _listOnTabSelectedEventHandlers.Add(null);

        //If this is the first tab, make it the opened one
        if(TabControl.Items.Count == 1)
            TabControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

So that's all well and good, but problems arise when the content-stripped window in question has bindings with converters. I've written a converter that inherits from MarkupExtension to avoid StaticReferences. My converter looks like this

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(Visibility))]
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool isWorking = (bool)value;
        if (isWorking)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

}
```

And the XAML that refers to it looks like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsEye, Converter={inf:BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <TextBlock Text="Working Eye" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Margin="5,5,0,0"/>
    <Button Content="Approve All" Command="{Binding ApproveAllTrades}" 
                        Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="auto" Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#DCDCDC"/>
 </StackPanel>
 <views:OrdersWorkingEyeView Loaded="EyeOrders_Loaded" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsEye, Converter={inf:BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Ignoring for the moment that BoolToVisibility is already a defined thing, when I strip the window of its content and load these two particular controls (one defined by me, the other a stack panel), a break point set at ProvideValue hits twice (once for each control), but Convert is only called once, for my custom control. The result is the custom control has the proper visibility but the stack panel does not. I'm pretty sure that the binding itself is working as the path for the bindings on the two controls is the same, and works for the custom control. I can't figure out what the difference is that is causing the conversion to occur for one but not the other (or, perhaps, why it's not binding properly for the StackPanel). Help?

*EDIT*

For what it's worth, everything works when I don't strip the content out of the window and put it in a new TabItem. The visibilities update and display fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your sample and I made the following changes to make it work

```
         private bool _isEye= true;

        public bool IsEye
        {
            get { return _isEye; }
            set { _isEye = value;
            NotifyFropertyChanged("IsEye");
            }
        }
```

Define resources

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- local is your namespace--> 
    <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

update the binding

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=IsEye,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

and it works for both usercontrol and stackpanel. 
Hope This might help.

Comment: My property already looks like that, and using that <Window.Resources> tag is what I had been doing before (except I was using styles defined in a merged dictionary) which, unfortunately, didn't work. The style gets thrown out and replaced when the window content is removed and inserted into the tab with newTab.Style = (Style)Resources["CorsairTab"];